# File content replacer for adding "build.counter" in version

Tags: regex, teamcity

I am using the "File content replacer" to replace "build number" with "build.counter" (13468) in the version string.

[image: File content replacer]

Here is the content in the file "AssemblyInfoVersion.cs".

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("3.0.1923.999")]
```

Here is the msg for "File content replacer"

```
File content replacer] Applying replacement "$113467$3" to lines matched by 
pattern "(^\s*\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*AssemblyVersionAttribute\s*\(\"[0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*]+\.)([0-9\*]+\.)([0-9\*]\"\)s*\])" 
 in the files matched by wildcard: **/AssemblyInfoVersion.cs...
 [14:28:44][File content replacer] Total files changed: 0.
 [14:28:44][File content replacer] No modifications were made: either no 
 text matching the pattern was found or the replaced text is the same as the 
 original
```

I am expecting to replace "1923" with "13468". It didn't nothing. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
`(^\s*\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*AssemblyVersionAttribute\s*\(\"[0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*]+\.)([0-9\*]+\.)([0-9\*]+\"\)s*\])`

The last `+` was missing in your regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that there's no match, because of a typo. Check this regex:

```
(^\s*\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*AssemblyVersionAttribute\s*\(\"[0-9\*]+\.[0-9\*]+\.)([0-9\*]+\.)([0-9\*]*\"\)s*\])
```

I have only added a star '`*`' after the last `[0-9\*]`* .
Then it matches.